# Count how many cells contain specific words in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm analyzing a large dataset and trying to figure out how to best count how many cells contain a particular set of words without duplicating cells where these words appear multiple times in a single cell. For example, I'd like to count the total number of cells that contain either "blue" OR "green" but only have cells labeled as "blue green" count once.

I've tried:

```
=countifs(A:A,"*blue*",A:A,"green")
```

or

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"*blue*","*green*"})))
```

but these don't address what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "(?i)blue|green"))
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks!  How do I make regexmatch case insensitive?  I'd like to return a positive count whether or not the word is spelled Blue, BLUE, or blue.

Comment: I updated the formula to make the regex pattern case insensitive.

Comment: @Meg: glad to hear ! Since you are new here, please check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)